# Jquery ui-sortable - how to drag tbody with tbody and tr with tr?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with several tbody in it, and obviously tr inside the tbody, what I  want is to sort tbody with tbody and tr with tr, but NOT mix the tbody inside a tr.

my javascript code is this:

```
$("#diagnosis_list").sortable({
        //helper: fixHelperModified,
        //fixed: $("side1")

        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.css('border', '1px solid red');
        },

        items: ".tbody, .abc",
        axis: "y",
        connectWith: ".tbody",

        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",

        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //reset to no border or whatever your desired default border is
            ui.item.css('border', '');
            renumber_table('#diagnosis_list');
        }

        //stop: function(event,ui) {renumber_table('#diagnosis_list')}
    }).disableSelection();
```

here you can check this out (you can see the wird behavior):
http://jsfiddle.net/elfstone321/yopk086n/

how do I achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have three `sortables`: one where ou sort you `tbodys`, and one for each `tbody` where you sort your `tr`.

For your `tbody` you'll need `handles`, else there's no way to know which `sortable` you want to target. This means that these `handles` won't work for the `tr` sortable.

You could for example define the first row of each table as the `handles` for `tbody sortable`. Then you jsut need to apply sortable to tr, except the first of each `tbody`. Like this for example:

```
 $("#diagnosis_list").sortable({

        handles: '.tbody > tr:first-child',//first row of each tbody will activate this sortable
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.css('border', '1px solid red');
        },
        items: ".tbody",//you only sort tbody
        axis: "y",
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //reset to no border or whatever your desired default border is
            ui.item.css('border', '');
            renumber_table('#diagnosis_list');
        }

    }).disableSelection();

    $("tbody").sortable({//you add sortable on each tbody, so <tr> are sortable

        items: 'tr:not(:first-child)',//you can sort all tr except the first one
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.css('border', '1px solid red');
        },
        axis: "y",
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            //reset to no border or whatever your desired default border is
            ui.item.css('border', '');
            renumber_table('#diagnosis_list');
        }
    }).disableSelection();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wx245bky/2/